# MySQL select by date range query - unexpected output

Tags: mysql, sql

Why MySQL in following query:

```
select * from `tips` 
where `tips`.`tipster_id` = '16' 
and `result` <> '0' 
and `date` >= '2014-02-01' 
and `date` <= '2014-02-28'
```

excludes rows with date **2014-02-28** ???

Comment: Yes, they are here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you store time values in that column? I guess that 2014-02-28 is this is the same as 2014-02-28 00:00:00.

So date values with a time after 00:00:00 will not be included.

Comment: Yes, I store time also, and time is not 00:00:00 but something like 15:20:00. Ok, I know what is the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use this version

```
select * from `tips` 
where `tips`.`tipster_id` = '16' 
and `result` <> '0' 
and `date` >= '2014-02-01 00:00:00' 
and `date` <= '2014-02-28 23:59:59'
```